# Prevent running Tor Browser on top of Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, debian

I installed Tor on Debian Wheezy: apt-get install tor
Then I downloaded and extracted: https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/4.0.2/tor-browser-linux64-4.0.2_en-US.tar.xz

When I run tor-browser, won't the embedded tor component cause a tor over tor situation?
To prevent, I followed https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/WebBrowsers#UseTorBrowserwithoutbundledTorNIX

Tor Browser now produces error: "Tor is not working in this browser"
What is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It will not cause a Tor-over-Tor situation. The Tor Browser launches its own instance of Tor that has its own connection to the Tor network regardless of other instances running.

(Running Tor on your host does not mean that everything (including your other Tor) automagically connects through it.)

Your browser is probably using Tor, but can not make a control connection. In that case your question is similar to this one of mine: [Using Tor Browser with alternate Tor client - works but issues warning](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4173/using-tor-browser-with-alternate-tor-client-works-but-issues-warning)