# Help need in a Tor router configuration error on Manjaro-Arm

Tags: linux, network-configuration, raspberry-pi

I want use Raspberry Pi3 as a TOR Router with Arm installed.
Here is my torrc configuration:

```
/etc/tor/torrc
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsSuffixes .onion,.exit
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 192.168.2.1
DNSPort 53
DNSListenAddress 192.168.2.1
```

These configuration work perfectly in Raspbian but when I wanna use them in Manjaro-Arm I got this error:

```
You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.2.1:53' for DNSPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.2.1:9040' for TransPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.2.1:53' for DNSPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
systemd[1]: tor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: tor.service: Unit entered failed state.
 systemd[1]: tor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The exact `systemctl status tor`[available here](https://paste.ubuntu.ir/beaf).

Can someone help me in this problem?
I did [read this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4173/using-tor-browser-with-alternate-tor-client-works-but-issues-warning) but it is of no help.
With configuration I mentioned tor works normally.

and when I start tor this way:

```
    [saeb@my-pi ~]$ /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc
Sep 10 17:18:23.343 [notice] Tor v0.2.8.7 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2h and Zlib 1.2.8.
Sep 10 17:18:23.343 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 10 17:18:23.348 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Sep 10 17:18:23.360 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.2.1:53' for DNSPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
Sep 10 17:18:23.360 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.2.1:9040' for TransPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
Sep 10 17:18:23.398 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.2.1:53' for DNSPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
Sep 10 17:18:23.398 [notice] You configured a non-loopback address '192.168.2.1:9040' for TransPort. This allows everybody on your local network to use your machine as a proxy. Make sure this is what you wanted.
Sep 10 17:18:23.398 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Sep 10 17:18:23.398 [notice] Opening DNS listener on 192.168.2.1:53
Sep 10 17:18:23.398 [warn] Could not bind to 192.168.2.1:53: Cannot assign requested address
Sep 10 17:18:23.398 [notice] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 192.168.2.1:9040
Sep 10 17:18:23.398 [warn] Could not bind to 192.168.2.1:9040: Cannot assign requested address
Sep 10 17:18:23.398 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Sep 10 17:18:23.399 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Sep 10 17:18:23.399 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: None of those messages are fatal errors, what does the full tor logs say? by default they should be located in `/var/lib/tor/`. If you could add that to your answer, that'd be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: that log file doesn't exist but I add more detail. tnx

Comment: derp! sorry I realised you said Manjaro which is an Arch derivative. Your tor logs will be in `journalctl -u tor`. The running it from the command line is probably not especially useful, for one you definitely won't be able to bind to port 53 as a regular user (required root privileges or capabilities, normally). Check journalctl and update with those logs. Thanks.